# How do I optimize 3D xyz nested for loops in Java and stream Vectors?

Tags: java, loops, stream

I write plugins for Minecraft and often hit a situation where I have to loop through every block in a 3-dimensional space to process the block in some way. For example:

```
for (int x = minX; x <= maxX; x++) {
    for (int y = minY; y <= maxY; y++) {
        for (int z = minZ; z <= maxZ; z++) {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

These kind of loops happen *a lot* and it struck me that perhaps there was a better way to do it that would make the code more concise but still be as fast to execute. All I really want to do is loop through every coordinate in a 3 dimensional type.

The Bukkit API has such a type - a `Vector` class that can hold x,y,z. The Vector class has methods such as `getBlockX`, `getBlockY` and `getBlockZ` that return integers. So, I was thinking of creating a utility method like this:

```
Stream<Vector> getXYZStream(minVector, maxVector)
```

This would return a stream of all the vectors (x,y,z) values between the min and max vectors given. So then I could do:

```
getXYZStream(minVector, maxVector).forEach(v -> doSomething);
```

How can I make a stream of vectors in this regard? If I can code this approach, then I'll measure the difference in performance and see if it makes sense.

Or is there a better way to do this?

Or should I accept these loops are necessary and the best approach?

Comment: This depends entirely on what `// Do something` does. Replacing the nested loops with an equivalent stream won't improve the running time, though it may improve the code readability.

Answer (score 0):

I found an approach where one can make a stream using a custom iterator, so one could do something like this:

```
    public Stream<Vector> get3dStream(Vector minVector, Vector maxVector) {
        Iterator<Vector> it = new CustomIterator(minVector, maxVector);
        return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(it, Spliterator.DISTINCT), false);
    }

    class CustomIterator implements Iterator<Vector> { 

        private Vector minVector;
        private Vector maxVector;

        BoundingBox b = new BoundingBox();

        // constructor 
        CustomIterator(Vector minVector, Vector maxVector) { 
            // initialize cursor
            this.minVector = minVector;
            this.maxVector = maxVector.add(new Vector(1,1,1));
        } 

        // Checks if the next element exists 
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return !minVector.equals(maxVector);
        } 

        // moves the cursor/iterator to next element
        @Override
        public Vector next() {
            Vector r = minVector;
            increment();
            return r;
        }

        private void increment() {
            // Increment the vector - this takes a lot of code to do
        } 

    }
```

However, as you can see, tracking the `next()` in the custom iterator will require quite a lot of code and comparing to the three for loops is much more complex and likely to be slower. I agree with the comment from kaya3, it could hide some of the looping, but it's not going to be faster, which is 100% a requirement.